# Hide iframe while it is loading subsequent content

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

So I am using `jQuery` to change content inside an `iframe` (same server), basically changing all colored elements to greyscale. The original content in the site is colored and I want to deliver a greyscale version of the site.

I have some code now that prevents the original colored iframe content from briefly showing on first load. I do this by first setting the iframe to be hidden...

```
#frame{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Then unhiding the `iframe` after all my changes have been made:

```
$('#frame').load(function(){
   ... various changes to css....
   $('frame').css('visiblity','');
});
```

So this works when the page is loaded or reloaded.

The problem comes when navigation occurs in the `iframe`. If a user clicks on some links in the `iframe`, it would jump to another page and for a brief moment, I would see colours again (until the css changes in `.load` are carried out). How can I make this more seamless?

**Edit: I would like to add that I do not wish to touch the code for the inner content.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my eventual solution was to simply assign a click listener to all `a` elements within the `iframe`.

```
$('#frame').contents().find('a').click(function(){
    $('#frame').css('visibility','hidden')
});
```

This hides the `iframe` temporarily while when a click is initiated inside, and becomes visible with the code I posted in the original question.